# asp.net mvc 3 razor. navigate to view on table tr click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have users list table how i can navigate on url: "../users/showprofile?userid="

I want to make table when user clicks on table row navigate on current user profile

Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Without using jQuery, assuming you're in a foreach loop like something below, just change the `tr` definition to be something like:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
{
    <tr onclick="location.href = '@(Url.Action("ShowProfile", "Users", new { userId = user.UserId }))'">
    //rest of your markup for that table row
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: it does not doing nothing. Can you help me?

Comment: Doh sorry I missed the `location.href = ` before it. Try my edit, it should work for you now.

Comment: Beautiful, Works nicely!