# Add clickable row to table in ASP Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core

ASP.NET CORE
I have a table and I want the **row to be clickable**, taking the user into a detail page. The row shall have a **link calling a controller action** called "Detail" with a report ID.

I have tried this answer but it does not work.
[asp.net mvc 3 razor. navigate to view on table tr click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470590/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-navigate-to-view-on-table-tr-click)

Please help.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayName("Report ID")
        </th>
        <th class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.DisplayName("Action")
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>

@foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
{
    <tr onclick="location.href='@Url.ActionLink("Detail", "ReportController", new { Id = item.ID })'">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Can you describe your needs in detail?

Comment: Which step are you not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to change your code like following.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MyList)
{
    <tr>
        <td onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("Detail", "Report", new { id = item.ID })'">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "Download", new { id = item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: Sadly, it still does not work. This is the body that was generated.

<tbody>
 <tr data-index="0">
  <td class="col-sm-2">99</td>
  <td class="col-sm-3">
   <a href="/Report/Detail/29">Detail</a>
  </td></tr>
</tbody>

Comment: But the above will only make the ID cell as a link, not the row. Oh well, small steps...

Comment: You should describe in detail at which step you can't work, is it that clicking Report ID can't work?

Comment: In your Report controller, there should be a matching action, and then query the model's information based on the ID and then return to the detail page.

Comment: In the end, I need to click on the entire row (<tr> </tr>). 
The onclick in the <td> is also not working. The ID is not clickable.

Comment: Make a endpoint In you `Detail` action,and click the line.not id

Comment: I created a small sample web app and applied your sample. It works!
However, just not on my main application. I am comparing both codes and trying to find the root cause of non-functioning link but so far no outcome. The sample cshtml was entirely copied from the original and trimmed, and it just work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231194/discussion-between-ed-l-005-and-yinqiu).

Answer (score 0):

This right here is just a quick view of some code that will link the entire row vs just a column. Hopefully someone will find this useful.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Countries.CountryList)
        {
            <tr onclick="location.href = '@Url.Page("/EditCountry", new { PK_CountryId = item.PK_CountryId })'">
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PK_CountryId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Countries)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Restricted)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RequireAESFilingYN)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

This below is what the code renders to in the HTML view source

```
           <tr onclick="location.href = '/EditCountry?PK_CountryId=AD'">
                <td>
                    AD
                </td>
                <td>
                    ANDORRA11
                </td>
                <td>
                    Y
                </td>
                <td>
                     
                </td>
            </tr>
```